# css not loading even though there're no errors and it's linked correctly in ejs

Tags: css, node.js, express, ejs

so, I'm trying to link a css file to an ejs file but it's not working, and I think I'm linking them correctly:

```
<head>
<title>Acres & Karats Calculator</title>
<base href="/">
<link type="text/css" href="css/Acres and Karats Calculator.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

and i specified the public directory to be used in express:

```
let express = require("express"),
    app     = express();

app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("Acres and Karats Calculator.ejs")
});

app.listen("3000", () => {
    console.log("Server started!");
});
```

and there are no errors in the console at all and the css is not loaded

file structure:

- app.js
- views

  - pubilc

    - css

      - Acres and Karats Calculator.css

Comment: i think there is a problem with your css name file

Comment: and please add your file structure too

Comment: Agreed, generally spaces aren't a good idea in file names. Try replacing spaces with underscores (`_`) or something similar. `Acres_and_Karats_Calculator.css`.

Comment: I tried replacing them with underscores but nothing happened

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding `rel="stylesheet"` and adding a / before the file path

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account the directory layout of your project:

```
app.js
views
-|_pubilc
---|_css
-----|_Acres and Karats Calculator.css
```

and the link to the `css` file in the `ejs` template:

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/Acres and Karats Calculator.css">
```

express static path in your `app.js` should be updated as follows:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/views/public"));
```

Comment: That didn't work, tried restarting the server and all, but didn't work